# How to change user alias on game center programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, game-center

i am working on a multiplayer game using gamecenter and i have to give edit profile option to user so user can update his/her alias and country.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with GameKit. Players data is read-only and can be changed in Settings app only. Source: [GKPlayer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKPlayer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKPlayer/displayName).

Comment: so there is no way to implement edit profile options ? or maybe i should show game center settings when user press edit profile option?

Comment: You are not allowed to open Settings app from your app. Your app would be rejected from App Store. All you can do is to inform the user that they need to go to settings to change their alias.